# Create a mock of ClientScriptManager with Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, asp.net, rhino-mocks

I would like to be able to mock the ClientScriptManager class on a webforms Page object,
however it seems like I can't, I get the error that I can't mock a sealed class.

```
MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository()

Page page = mocks.PartialMock<Page>();

var clientScript = mocks.PartialMock<ClientScriptManager>(); //error here

SetupResult.For(page.ClientScript).Return(clientScript);
```

Any advice on how to mock the clientscriptmanager would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've discovered, you can't use most mocking libraries to mock sealed types. One reason for this is that many mock libraries operate by creating a derived type but if the class is sealed then they can't derive from it.

What we've done internally at Microsoft is that we use a hand-written `IClientScriptManager` interface and then use a `ClientScriptManagerWrapper` that implements that interface and delegates all calls to a real `ClientScriptManager`.

Then whatever type needs to use the `ClientScriptManager` it will instead have a reference to an `IClientScriptManager`. At runtime we create a `ClientScriptManagerWrapper` (and pass in the real `ClientScriptManager`). At test time we use a mock object library to create a mock `IClientScriptManager` and use that instead.

And here's a code sample:

```
public class SomeClassThatNeedsClientScriptManager {
    private IClientScriptManager _iClientScriptManager;

    public IClientScriptManager IClientScriptManager {
        get {
            if (_iClientScriptManager == null) {
                _iClientScriptManager = new ClientScriptManagerWrapper(Page.ClientScriptManager);
            }
            return _iClientScriptManager;
        }
        set {
            _iClientScriptManager = value;
        }
    }

    public void SomeMethodThatUsesClientScriptManager() {
        IClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Whatever), "key", "alert('hello')");
    }
}

public interface IClientScriptManager {
    void RegisterClientScriptBlock(Type type, string key, string script);
}

public class ClientScriptManagerWrapper : IClientScriptManager {
    private readonly ClientScriptManager _clientScriptManager;

    public ClientScriptManagerWrapper(ClientScriptManager clientScriptManager) {
        if (clientScriptManager == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("clientScriptManager");
        }
        _clientScriptManager = clientScriptManager;
    }

    public void RegisterClientScriptBlock(Type type, string key, string script) {
        _clientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(type, key, script);
    }
}
```

You can then modify the `IClientScriptManager` interface and the `ClientScriptManagerWrapper` to have whatever methods you need.

Comment: It's too bad that this is internal. I would love to see more Framework types implement public interfaces and wrappers so that testable code can be interoperable with fewer layers. But that's why we tend to wrap the wrappers. :)

Comment: @maxwellb indeed if you look at most of the newer frameworks (certainly in the ASP.NET space), you'll see lots more interfaces and abstract base classes. For example, MVC, Web API, and SignalR all make heavy use of interfaces, which makes this type of scenario a lot easier to implement.